# Is it possible to code CRUD operations in kendo LISTVIEW with local data?

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, datasource, local, crud

I am trying to **add** data into a local json variable using a listview. I have wrapped up my data array inside a kendo datasource, which is part of my viewmodel.

The problem is that by the time the "Create" action in the transport is reached, my local array has **not** been updatedy, however my viewmodel.dataSource.data was actually. How do I get my local data array updated when the create action in the transport is reached.

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ADTM/) with my code.

```
    var data =
        [{
            "ID": 3,
            "TopMenuId": 2,
            "Title": "Cashier",
            "Link": "www.fake123.com"
        },
        {
            "ID": 4,
            "TopMenuId": 2,
            "Title": "Deposit",
            "Link": "www.fake123.com"
        }
        ];

    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    alert("Read");
                    options.success(data);
                },
                create: function (options) {
                    debugger;

                    alert("Create");
                    alert(data.length);
                },
                update: function (options) {
                    alert("Update");
                },
                destroy: function (options) {
                    alert("Destroy");
                    alert(data.length);
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 4,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: {
                            editable: false,
                            nullable: true
                        },
                        TopMenuId: {
                            editable: false,
                            nullable: true
                        },
                        Title: {
                            editable: true,
                            validation: {
                                required: true
                            }
                        },
                        Link: {
                            editable: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                data: "",
                total: function (result) {
                    result = result.data || result;
                    return result.length || 0;
                }
            },
        }),
    });

    //kendo.init($("#briefOverview"));
    $(document).ready(function () {

        kendo.bind($("#briefOverview"), viewModel);
        $(".k-add-button").click(function (e) {
            var listView = $("#listsContainer").data("kendoListView");
            listView.add();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `create` method in transport is invoked for actually updating your dataSource, no matter if it is local or remote you are expected to do so.

So some consideration in your case are:

1. You need to update your local dataSource (append the element).
2. You need to assign an `id` (you are expected that when `create` finishes the `id` has a non-default value (in your case a value different than null).
3. Finally, you should invoke `options.success` with the element as returned from the server (typically with the assigned `id`) in your case (being local) just the same thing that you received but with `ID` filled.

So your `create` method should be:

```
create: function (options) {
    debugger;
    var item = options.data.models[0];
    // assign an ID, here I pick a Kendo generated UID
    item.ID = kendo.guid();
    data.push(item);
    alert("Create with ID: " + item.ID);
    alert(data.length);
    options.success(item);
},
```

and your JSFiddle modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/3ADTM/1/

And BTW, you should also invoke `options.success` on `update`:

```
update: function (options) {
    alert("Update");
    options.success(options.data.models[0]);
},
```

Your final JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3ADTM/2/